# Magento2: Asymmetric transaction rollback

Tags: magento2, database, indexer, transaction

Sometimes I found in log file issue:

```
Ran jobs by schedule.
string(32) "Asymmetric transaction rollback."
Ran jobs by schedule.
Ran jobs by schedule.
Ran jobs by schedule.
```

Anyone know how it is and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this follow following steps:

Reset and reindex indexes

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Remove cache and delete/rename  /var and /generated (in case of magento 2.2) folders

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**EDIT:**

It may be due to other sql process query having lock on the desired row, use

```
 SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

in phpmyadmin/ mysql-cli to get all processes and kill the processes if you have to or wait for some time and try again later.(I think you must have set reindex by schedule and cron must be running right now).

Comment: I check and: I have 2 index still on red "Proccessing" When I try reindex via ssh then for this 2 indexes: "Indexes locked by other reindex. Skipping." I have try reset index and again reindex but I get error: deadlock.  I try to solve issue deadlock  https://www.tigren.com/fix-deadlock-error-reindexing-magento-2/ but no work for me.  Any solution ?

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: Ok Vivek thank you I check your solution.

Comment: It did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem can be solved by following steps

1. Reset and Reindex by using the following command

   ```
   php bin/magento indexer:reset 
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
2. run below commands

   ```bash
   rm -rf var/cache/*
   rm -rf var/page_cache/*
   rm -rf var/generation/*
   ```
3. Give permissions to `var/generation` folder.